# Admin Style Navigation with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for a resource/tutorial on how to make a navigation bar that mimics Worpdress' Admin section.  I'm trying to make a navigation bar that is fixed to the side of the screen, when the bar is collapsed I'm wanting a list of icons to be present so the user knows the nav bar has not faded away.

This is an example of what I'm looking for: http://demo.neontheme.com/dashboard/main-3/

I've noticed the phrase "admin" with most of these themes and I cannot find a good tutorial at this point.

Any help is appreciated.  Please ask for more info before any down votes.

Comment: Can you show, what you have been tried ?

Comment: I really haven't tried anything as of yet.  I've been looking for a tutorial or plugin that I could look at to learn how it's done.  I'm looking at expanding my jQuery knowledge, but driving straight end I think could be more problematic than working from a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would require quite a few different elements and I have not seen a single tutorial that would show you everything at once.

To get started though check out these two tutorials on "push" and "slide over" menus. That should get you pretty close to where you wanna be.

http://youtu.be/_RPFalOGOJU

and

http://youtu.be/ccqRk7Ehru4

Scott from LevelUp Tuts has load of other CSS videos as well, when you get stuck on something just refer back to those vids and you can usually find something to help you out.

Comment: No problem. Good luck, let us see how its going once you get started!